# getting intval() using php?

Tags: php, function, integer

let's say I have the following string:

```
danger13 afno 1 900004
```

using `intval()` it gives me 13, however, I want to grab the highest integer in the string, which is 9000004, how can I achieve this?

Edit: the string comes in different forms, and I don't know where the highest number will be.

Comment: One way that comes to mind is split string into array using `explode()`, walk through each member, find highest one

Comment: Does the string always have the same format? Do you want "the highest number" from the string or always *the last number* in the string?

Comment: `intval('danger13 afno 1 900004')` does not give you `13`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to get all the integers out of the string, then find the biggest...

```
$str = "danger13 afno 1 900004";
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $str, $matches); // get all the number-only patterns
$numbers = $matches[0];

$numbers = array_map('intval', $numbers); // convert them to integers from string

$max = max($numbers); // get the largest
```

`$max` is now `900004`.

Note that this is *very* simple. If your string has anything that matches the pattern `\d+` (1 or more digits) that you don't want to match as a separate integer (e.g. `43.535` would return `535`), this won't be satisfactory for you. You'll need to define more closely what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

For the lexicographical highest integer value within the string (up to `PHP_INT_MAX`) you can just split the numbers apart and get the maximum value:

```
$max = max(preg_split('/[^\d]+/', $str, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/LaXoucAf).

Or better self-documenting:

```
$digitsList = preg_split('/[^\d]+/', $str, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
if (!$digitsList)
{
    throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Unexpected state; string "%s" has no digits.', $str));
}
$max = max($digitsList);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$nums=preg_split('/[^\d\.]+/',$string); //splits on non-numeric characters & allows for decimals
echo max($nums);
```

ETA: updated to allow for "words" that end in or contain numbers (Thanks Gordon!)

Comment: @Gordon: point taken.  `preg_split` and filtre out alphas before max would work better.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$string = 'danger13 afno 1 900004';

preg_match_all('/[\d]+/', $string, $matches);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($matches,1).'</pre>';

$highest = array_shift($matches[0]);

foreach($matches[0] as $v) {
  if ($highest < $v) {
    $highest = $v;
  }
}

echo $highest;

?>
```